# How to shorten this code or make it more efficient?

Tags: java

How to shorten up this code? I know there's a way that this kind of code could be shortened, but I don't know how by myself yet. Who can help me?

```
            //CHOOSE LEVEL: FROZEN
case 1213:
    sendOption5("Level 1 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 1 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 2 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 2 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 3 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 3 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 4 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 4 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "More");
    c.dialogueAction = 1213;
    break;
case 1214:
    sendOption5("Level 5 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 5 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 6 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 6 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 7 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 7 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 8 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 8 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "More");
    c.dialogueAction = 1214;
    break;
case 1215:
    sendOption5("Level 9 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 9 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 10 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 10 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "Level 11 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 11 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",
            "",
            "Choose Floor");
    c.dialogueAction = 1215;
    break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you explain a bit about the context of the code? What is it used for? What is it doing? Providing some context will likely give you better reviews.

Answer (score 8):

In a first step I would extract a method to generate the string.

changed code:

```
            //CHOOSE LEVEL: FROZEN
case 1213:
    sendOption5(
            levelString( 1, c),
            levelString( 2, c),
            levelString( 3, c),
            levelString( 4, c),
            "More");
    c.dialogueAction = 1213; 
    break;
case 1214:
    sendOption5(
            levelString( 5, c),
            levelString( 6, c),
            levelString( 7, c),
            levelString( 8, c),
            "More");
    c.dialogueAction = 1214;
    break;
case 1215:
    sendOption5(
            levelString( 9, c),
            levelString(10, c),
            levelString(11, c),
            "",
            "Choose Floor");
    c.dialogueAction = 1215;
    break;
```

extracted method:

```
private static String levelString(int i, TypeOfC c){
   return "Level " + i + (c.achievedFloor <= i ? " @gre@(Achieved)" : " @red@(Not achieved)");
}
```

You should also think about changing the parameters of your `sendOption5` to get only `c` and two integers `from` `to` which define the inteval of values.

And you can move the `c.dialogueAction = xxxx;` line behind the `switch` and assign the value you use for the `switch`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two sets of repeating  code here. The standard solution to DRY (Don't repeat yourself) is Function Extraction.

Consider two functions:

```
private static String levelAchievedOption(int level, int achieved) {
    return String.format("Level %d @%s", level,
         achieved >= level ? "gre@(Achieved)" : "red@(Not Achieved)");
}
```

Then, the second function for setting the options:

```
private static void setLevelOptions(int levela, int levelb, int levelc, int leveld, String postfix, int levelAchieved) {
    sendOption5(
        levela >= 0 ? levelAchievedOption(levela, levelAchieved) : "",
        levelb >= 0 ? levelAchievedOption(levelb, levelAchieved) : "",
        levelc >= 0 ? levelAchievedOption(levelc, levelAchieved) : "",
        leveld >= 0 ? levelAchievedOption(leveld, levelAchieved) : "",
        postfix);
}
```

Then, your case statement can become:

```
case 1213:
    setLevelOptions(1, 2, 3, 4, "More", c.achievedFloor);
    c.dialogueAction = 1213;
    break;
case 1214:
    setLevelOptions(5, 6, 7, 8, "More", c.achievedFloor);
    c.dialogueAction = 1214;
    break;
case 1215:
    setLevelOptions(9, 10, 11, -1, "Choose Floor", c.achievedFloor);
    c.dialogueAction = 1215;
    break;
```

Comment: I think there is an error or maybe I am not understanding clearly. But, in `levelAchievedOption(levela >= 0 ? levelAchievedOption(levela, levelAchieved) : "")` `levelAchievedOption` takes one `int` and another `String` parameter. So howcome outer `levelAchievedOption` will be invoked with only one `String`?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good talk about it by a Google's employee (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc).
In fact these kind of conditions can be avoided using inheritance.
You could create 3 different implementations of an abstract class which all have a method sendOption5() and you could choose one of it using a case.
A better way to do it, but it depends on your code is to create an abstract class (or interface) like

```
interface Option
{
  public void sendOptions();
  public boolean haveToBeCalled(Integer number);
}
```

where haveToBeCalled returns true if number if a certain value, false otherwise.
And so if you have a list of "Option" you can use it as

```
for (Option o : options)
{
  if (o.haveToBeCalled(number))
  {
    o.sendOptions();
  }
}
```

Anyway, it really depends on the rest of your code. The kind of scheme you're can often be improved by refactoring a part of the code.

Comment: I know this, but I was more talking about lines like these: "Level 6 " + (c.achievedFloor <= 6 ? "@gre@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)") + "",

Comment: why don't you create a method that generate your string depending on "c"?

Answer (score 3):

My best guess will be create a method to build your `String`s and make `sendOption5` a method that takes `List` of `String`. You can also use var-args.

```
List<String> levelDescriptions;
Case 1213:
    levelDescriptions = generateStringUponLevelNumber(c,1,2,3,4);
    levelDescriptions.add("More");
    sendOption5(levelDescriptions);

    c.dialogueAction = caseNumber;
// same goes for others

------

public static List<String> generateStringUponLevelNumber(TypeOf c, int... levels) {
    List<String> levelDescription = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int level : levels) {
        String description = "Level " + level + " ";
        description += c.achievedFloor <= level ? "@green@(Achieved)" : "@red@(Not achieved)";
        levelDescription.add(description);
    }
    return levelDescription;
}
```

---

### After OP's comment

Change your method accordingly

```
public void sendOption5(List<String> levelDescriptions) {
    c.getPA().sendFrame126("Select an Option", 2493);
    for(int level = 0, from = 2494; level <= 4; level++, from++) {
        c.getPA().sendFrame126(levelDescriptions.get(level), from);
    }
    c.getPA().sendFrame164(2492);
}
```

**Some suggestion upon naming**

1. The method name `sendOption5` is misleading. Cause if someone is seeing the code and see the name he/she will think there are **N** options and you are sending the 5<sup>th</sup> option as parameter, which is not true. You are sending 5 Strings or options. So the apt. name would be `sendFiveOptions`.

Comment: This was pretty helpful but my method wont work anymore which is: 'code'( public void sendOption5(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
  c.getPA().sendFrame126("Select an Option", 2493);
  c.getPA().sendFrame126(s, 2494);
  c.getPA().sendFrame126(s1, 2495);
  c.getPA().sendFrame126(s2, 2496);
  c.getPA().sendFrame126(s3, 2497);
  c.getPA().sendFrame126(s4, 2498);
  c.getPA().sendFrame164(2492);
 })

Comment: @user3395769 see the changes. Though I highly recommend you to further refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like it's probably easiest to pre-build all the strings, then select four to use. First, I think you probably want to re-check your logic on one minor point. Did you really mean `<=` when you did the comparisons to `c.achievedFloor`? Typically you'd expect floors to be achieved in order, so if (for example) the player has achieved floor 7, that means they've also achieved floors 1 through 6. The way you've written seems to imply the reverse--that achieving (for example) level 4 means they've also achieved levels 5 though 10.

Anyway, for the moment, let's assume the logic is correct and roll with it.

In that case, I'd start by building a table of strings:

```
int i;
floors[12] = "";
for (i=11; i>=c.achievedFloor; i--)
   floors[i] = ""@gre@(Achieved)";
for ( ; i>0; i--)
   floors[i] = "@red@(Not achieved)";
```

Since you haven't shown its name, I'm going to assume the value you're using in the `case` statements is named `input`.

The values you're using (`1214`, `1215`, ...) should probably be given some sort of meaningful name. Right now, they're pretty much the essence of magic numbers. For the moment, I'm going to assign the name `first` to 1213 and `last` to 1215.

Using that, we'd have something like:

```
int base = (input - first) / 4;
SendOption5(floors[base], floors[base+1], floors[base+2], floors[base+3], 
    input == last ? "" : "More");
c.DialogAction = input;
```